# How do I create a tri-colored arc in Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape, shapes, data-visualisation

I need to cut an arc which has three colors say red, green and blue one after the other. This is for a circular game paddle.

I am using a differentiate on a square and a circle, then rotating the entire thing and deleting the longer arc-path and changing the color of the smaller-arc.

Is there a simpler and more efficient method to create a tri-color arc?

Here is a glimpse of my effort:

[image]
[image: My unsuccessful attempt]

Now I need to make each section of the arc uniform. I want easy ways to use angle or specify size percent.

I found these formulas:

http://www.regentsprep.org/regents/math/geometry/gp15/circlearcs.htm

Comment: What do you mean with make it uniform? maybe you could use masks?

Comment: @Luciano The length of each color must be same in radius . The one I drew apparently doesn't have uniform lengths.

Comment: So the 3 colors must have the same lenght? I'm not an inkscape user, but if you know the total lenght of the arc (or the angle) can't you just simply draw a circle and cut / rotate the arcs?

Comment: @Luciano I'm unable to make the arcs centered. The centered. The center changes once I cut it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

1. Start by drawing a circle using the Circle tool, whilst holding down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>
2. Turn on "Snap to object centre" & "Snap to rotation centre" and create guides that snap to the centre of the circle

[image]

3. With the circle tool and circle still selected, **you can calculate the arc length you desire by expressing it as a percentage fraction X 360**. i.e. (25/100)*360 can be typed directly into the "End" box to give you 25% arc length which is 90 degrees. Note: the brackets are important.
4. Make sure you click "Switch to arc" after you calculate the arc size.
5. With the Selection tool, click the rotation point and move it to the guide intersection. We want to rotate and duplicate the arc around this point.

[image]

6. Clone the arc with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, and click the arc layer again to make the rotation handles appear. Use the selection tool to rotate the arc around the pivot point, and press <kbd>SPACEBAR</kbd> to clone/stamp the arc around this point.

[image]

7. Select all clones and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to unlink clones. You can now remove any fills and enter the arc stroke colours as you wish.

[image]

**For different arc lengths**: After you Unlink your arc clones, you can enter different values into the "End" box (whilst the circle tool is selected) for each arc. Make sure you move the centrepoints of the arcs into the intersecting guides & rotate each arc to join them together.

[image]

Comment: Just what I was looking for. Now I hope somebody gives a Pie plugin based answer or find the plugin myself.